# How to change path of $UserBaseDirectory to a new location during startup?

Tags: front-end, customization, kernel-startup, default, files-and-directories

I wish to customize where packages and notebooks are saved by creating a custom directory tree which emulates Mathematica defaults. I wish to do this so that paths can be found in $ContextPath for loading packages. This will be done during development. Of course after packages (and other files) are proven to work they will be saved to Mathematica's default locations.

I recall finding a way to change in documentation for when Kernel is loading or when FrontEnd loads. But I can no longer find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an environment variable which you can set to do this:

MATHEMATICA_USERBASE

more details can be found in the tutorial about wolfram system sessions:

tutorial/GlobalAspectsOfWolframSystemSessions#122753064

Comment: thank you this works.